# how to validate dom manipulation from server side

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have replaced inner html content of div tag, as follows.

```
document.getElementById("fp_min_reward").innerHTML = "0.10";
```

after refreshing the page the change has gone...how to fix it?

Comment: Please paste all of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the details of the change somewhere.

If this needs to be shared with other users then that place has to be on the server. You can use Ajax to make an HTTP request containing the details and then record the information using the server-side language of your choice. Typically you would do this in a database. When the page is requested, it should be generated from a server side program that checks said database. (This is essentially a CMS).

If the change is on a per-user basis then you *can* store it server-side, but you then need to record which user the change is for. You could do this with a user id in the database table. If the change needs to exist only for a short time, then you could record it in a session.

Alternatively (and only if this is on a per-user basis) you could record the information in the browser. The Local Storage API is a common choice for this. You would then need a script which runs when the document loads to check for a record in Local Storage and reapply the change to the DOM if said record exists.